# How to make VS Code see methods and properties first

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

When i type :

$some = new Some();

$some->

I first see realy much trash in the form of base functions, global variables and etc.
But not methods or properties of class.

I will see this only if i will type more symbols, but its very inconveniently .

I already install "php intelephense", "php intellisense" and "phpfmt" intentions, but this hasn't helped.

How it looks like:
[image: How it looks like]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should disable `php.suggest.basic` parameter in VSCode settings (paste in search on settings page)